# Исключение Cannot contact site at the specified URL при выполнении ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

Я пытаюсь получить список с удаленного Sharepoint 2013 сервера из Web application которое использует sharepoint CSOM, при этом по достижении первого `ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()` выдается исключение **Cannot contact site at the specified URL**. Если я выполняю это приложение на локальном сервере - все отлично работает. На сервере включена только Windows auth, права для учетной записи Application pool - Администратор сайта, Администратор фермы.

Использую следующий код:

```
    public string testRest()
    {
        try
        {
            ClientContext context = new ClientContext(new Uri(@"http://sharepointRemoteServer/sites/subsite"));
            context.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
            context.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
            List spList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("ListName");
            context.Load(spList);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            return "OK";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Посмотрите этот пример решения: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23739437/error-cannot-contact-site-at-the-specified-url-there-is-no-web-named-asmx , вот еще примерное решение https://vasya10.wordpress.com/tag/cannot-contact-site-at-specified-url/

Comment: @MikhailZhuykov Прошел по приведенной статье и выяснил, что вызывается `/_vti_bin/sites.asmx`, а в ответ - **object reference not set to an instance of an object**
При этом в лог сыпется:`Application error when access /sites/subsite/_vti_bin/sites.asmx, Error=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.   at ASP.global_asax.Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
    at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() 
    at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ок. Проблема решена. Для возможности кросс-сайтовых rest-запросов в global.asax был добавлен JS, который перехватывал все запросы и менял их заголовок. В этом JS было условие в котором получался user agent, т.к. приложение user agent не отдает - выдавалась ошибка.